# mvn clean install locally works but not in github actions

Tags: maven, github, github-actions

I am trying to write a simple GitHub workflow where it will install and run tests for my maven project. when I try to run `mvn clean install` locally the tests run but not when it runs on the pipeline. It keeps showing zero test run. What could be the possible reason?

```
name: Build and Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: feat/add-test

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 11
          distribution: 'adopt'
          cache: maven
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: mvn package -DskipTests
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install
      - name: Run Formatter
        run: mvn com.coveo:fmt-maven-plugin:format
      - name: Test
        run: | 
          mvn clean test
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <groupId>speed</groupId>
    <artifactId>simulator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.11</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- junit  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your workflow in your question.

Comment: @Azeem added the workflow

Comment: Why running `mvn package` and another time `mvn clean install` and furthermore `mvn clean test`... just use a single `mvn verify` that will include `package` also `test`etc. An `install` does not make sense on Github

Comment: i use the mvn clean install for testing to simulate what is happening on my local. but I can see that the run but it keep appears 0 test

Comment: ` testing to simulate what is happening on..` The `install` will only copy the artifacts in the local cache... that is useless... More important why the tests not running... Please show the pom file...

Comment: added the pom file

Comment: i manage to fix it. it's using a different maven-surefire-plugin as I didn't specify in the plugins

Comment: The log output does not show the version of the maven-surefire-plugin...? Can you tell me?

Comment: Use most most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin... 3.2.5 (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) furthermore I recommend to use the bom setup for junit jupiter and mockito etc. check here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/tree/main/episode-2

Comment: Is there a typo in the question? `showing zero test runner` -> `showing zero test run`?